# nav class not working after using a route with id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, navbar

i am troubling with problem here is my html:

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('warehouse.update.page', $warehouse->id) }}">Edit</a>
```

but after going to this page that view update page. my navigation bar url's start behaving weird.

when I view the warehouse list my URL is
http://127.0.0.1:8000/omni-warehouse

[image]

[image]

when I view a specific warehouse to update with an id the url is
http://127.0.0.1:8000/warehouse-update-page/1
and my side navbar behave weird.

one of the console error url is here
http://127.0.0.1:8000/outlet-update-page/assets/images/layouts/horizontal-top-nav.png
Please  Help Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take more care creating your question.  What you have posted is barely readable which does not say much for your ability to create reliable code.

Comment: How you're loading css in .blade file?

Comment: @Snapey sure sir.

Comment: @HaxxanRaxa this is my default theme in which theme color dynamically set now the css is not loading and i am loading css files using jquery thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is being loaded relative to the current page. It needs to be relative to the route (ie, start with `/`) or use the asset helper which will insert the correct path.

Comment: Thanks @Snapey i just inserted my link again on master file and its works. and some image src are not encoded in laravel asset functions that cause this error so i correct it. thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "It needs to be relative to the root"  not route